# Express server not listening to get url request and returning to / always

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I have the following express server setup:

```
const express = require('express');
    const path = require('path');
    const app = express();

    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));

    app.get('/', function (req, res) {
        console.log('/*');
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
    });

    app.get('/test', function (req, res) {
        console.log('test');
        //res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
    });

    app.listen(9000);
```

Everytime I hit localhost:9000/test, it still take to the route '/'. 
I tried placing the app.get code before the static declaration but I don't think that really makes any difference. Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Your existing code is fine. It should work.

I believe you had your index route as `app.get('/*', function (req, res){` instead of `app.get('/', function (req, res) {` before and that's why it was capturing all requests.

Comment: I had '/' and then tried with '/*' whic is why console.log has that. I am not sure at all why that is not working

Answer (score 0):

In the `/test` route handler you have to terminate the request-response cycle by using `res.end()`, something like this:

```
app.get('/test', function (req, res) {
    console.log('test');
    res.end();
});
```

Otherwise the page will never refresh showing the first page (route /)

Hope this helps